# reading a binary file in c++ just like in python

Tags: python, c++, file, stream, binary

I want to read a file in binary mode in c++. Initially i was using python to do the same when i read the same file using python i got the result `b'\xe0\xa4\xb5\xe0\xa4\xbe\xe0\xa4\xb9'` which when converted to INT resulted in `224 164 181 224 164 190 224 164 185` and i am able to notice that all these INTs are always in the range `[0,255]`.

I want to do the same thing in c++ but am unabale to do the same I have tried a lot of diffrent tricks but the best i could get was c++ giving negative integers.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <io.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    std::fstream file("a.txt", std::ios::out | std::ios::in | std::ios::binary);
    file.seekg(0, std::ios::end);
    int size = file.tellg();
    char ch;
    std::string text;
    std::cout << "Size = " << size << std::endl;
    file.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);
    char x;
    file.read((&x), 1);
    std::cout << static_cast<int>(x) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

please ignore the `#include` i have used way lot of them.

```
OUTPUT

Size = 9
-32
```

Comment: Cast the value to an `unsigned int` when you print it.

Comment: Hey but that results in ```4294967264``` as output but as i told i wanted to read the file such that i get INTs in range ```[0,255]``` can you suggest any way to do this

Comment: Stop reading `char`s. They are often signed. Use `unsigned char` or `<cstdint>`'s `uint8_t` instead. `std::byte` if you got 'em.

Comment: -32 is the same bit pattern as 224. Just depends how you visualize it. `https://ideone.com/hvekS6

Comment: when you use `char` then it treats it as `signed char` with value in range `[-128, 127]` and then `224` means `-32`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, the issue here is that `char` by default, is signed - meaning it takes values in the range `[-128, 127]`. This was, 224 will roll over to the negative end and become `-32`.
You should use an `unsigned char`, which will make the range `[0, 255]`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <io.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    std::fstream file("a.txt", std::ios::out | std::ios::in | std::ios::binary);
    file.seekg(0, std::ios::end);
    int size = file.tellg();
    unsigned char ch;
    std::string text;
    std::cout << "Size = " << size << std::endl;
    file.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);
    unsigned char x;
    file.read((&x), 1);
    std::cout << static_cast<int>(x) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```